# Monitor current dB level in cocoa touch (iPhone)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

So essentially I just want to monitor the current dB level being picked up by the microphone(s?) in the iPhone with mostly objective c code. I looked around on google and it looks like you need to do some "hardcore" c programming with AudioQueues to get it working. I'm not great at C coding so the code below is my attempt to use the bare minimum C coding to get a result I can send back into my warm and familiar objective-c land. The problem is, I can't seem to create the AudioQueue , the 'status' I get back is -50 which is 'unknown error'.

I'm essentially setting up the Audio queue in my viewDidLoad and declaring a c callback above it and from within the call back I grab the current dB value and send that back into objective c land but the callback never gets called because the AudioQueue isn't getting created properly and I have no idea why. Anyone able to see something I'm doing wrong or point me in the direction of an objective c wrapper for this audio stuff. Cheers.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    AudioQueueRef mQueue;
}

- (void)receivedSoundOfPower:(Float32)power;

@end

@implementation ViewController


void MyInputBufferHandler(  void *                              inUserData,
                                      AudioQueueRef                     inAQ,
                                      AudioQueueBufferRef                   inBuffer,
                                      const AudioTimeStamp *                inStartTime,
                                      UInt32                                inNumPackets,
                                      const AudioStreamPacketDescription*   inPacketDesc)
{
    ViewController *self = (__bridge id)inUserData;

    AudioQueueLevelMeterState meters[1];
    UInt32 dlen = sizeof(meters);
    OSStatus status = AudioQueueGetProperty(inAQ,kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeterDB,meters,&dlen);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        Float32 peakPower = meters[0].mPeakPower;
        [self receivedSoundOfPower:peakPower];
    }
}

- (void)receivedSoundOfPower:(Float32)power
{
    NSLog(@"%f", power);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    OSStatus status =AudioQueueNewInput(kAudioStreamAnyRate,
                                MyInputBufferHandler,
                                (__bridge void *)(self),
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                0,
                                &(mQueue));

    NSLog(@"%ld", status);

    // Turn on level metering (iOS 2.0 and later)
    UInt32 on = 1;
    AudioQueueSetProperty(mQueue,kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering,&on,sizeof(on));

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use Audio Queues just to get the DB values. You can do something more like:

```
- (void)setup {
    // record audio to /dev/null
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

    // some settings
    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];

    // create a AVAudioRecorder
    NSError *error;
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if (recorder) {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01f target:self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    }
}

- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];

    // here is the DB!
    float peakDecebels =  [recorder peakPowerForChannel:1];
            float avaeragePower = [recorder averagePowerForChannel:1];
}
```

Also if you are looking to access the audio data, this library is superb: http://alexbw.github.com/novocaine/

Comment: Thanks man! I'll try this when I get home :) That looks much easier. Does recording audio to dev/null do anything special? I don't want to store the data/run into memory issues (This process would be running non stop for up to 10 hours) so should I be deleting the data in the call back each time? Thanks again.

Comment: The system will discard anything written to /dev/null/ so you should be fine.

Comment: Great! Thanks for that. Works like a charm! It seems that peakPowerForChannel resets every second, so if there is a loud sound for a fraction of a second, it will return 0.00 (the highest value) for a full second. So I ended up going for averagePowerForChannel :D

Comment: It always show -160 for me on both peak and average... any leads on why this is happening? Because I am recording the audio and playing it with no problems...

Comment: Just a thought... are you calling `updateMeters`? And set `meteringEnabled` to `YES`?

Comment: A problem with AVAudioRecording's metering is that it's smoothed, resulting in those lingering peaks that @GeorgeMcKibbin mentioned.